# Passing parameters to function in pandas.DataFrame.transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, transform

I wrote an example where I want to pass mask_size as parameter in mask_first used by pandas.DataFrame.transform.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
a = [a for a in [1,2,3,4,5] for i in range(25)]
b = [random.randrange(1, 10) for _ in range(0, 125)]
d = {'col1': a, 'col2': b}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
def mask_first(df, mask_size):
    result = np.ones_like(df)
    result[0:mask_size] = 0
    return result
def apply_mask(df, mask_size = 10):
    mask = df.groupby(['col1'])['col1'].transform(mask_first).astype(bool)
    df = df.loc[mask]
    return df
df = apply_mask(df, mask_size = 10)
```

It gives me the error code

> TypeError: mask_first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mask_size'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html#pandas-dataframe-transform), you should be able to pass arguments to the function using the `transform` method itself:

```
DataFrame.transform(func, axis=0, *args, **kwargs)
```

Where (extract from pandas docs):

> *args: Positional arguments to pass to func.
>
> **kwargs: Keyword arguments to pass to func.

Try doing this to pass the mask size argument to your `mask_first` function:

```
# Important part: .transform(mask_first, mask_size)
mask = df.groupby(['col1'])['col1'].transform(mask_first, mask_size).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Straight forward, thanks a lot. This is the perfect solution for my problem.